# Вывод на экран

Tags: ассемблер

Подскажите как в Assebmler вывести на экран слово Hello

Answer (score 6):

1. Fasm, через MessageBox:

   ```
   include 'win32ax.inc'

   .code

   start:
       invoke MessageBox,HWND_DESKTOP,'Hello!','Title',MB_OK
       invoke ExitProcess, 0

   .end start
   ```
2. Fasm, консоль, через WriteConsole:

   ```
   format pe console
   include 'win32ax.inc'

   .data
       hOut dd ?
   .code
       sHello db 'Hello!'
       .length = $ - sHello

   start:
       invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
       mov [hOut], eax ; на случай если будет использоваться не один раз
       invoke WriteConsole, [hOut], sHello, sHello.length, 0, 0
       invoke ExitProcess, 0

   .end start
   ```
3. Fasm, консоль, через puts из msvcrt:

   ```
   format pe console
   entry start

   include 'win32ax.inc'

   section '.code' code readable executable
   start:
       cinvoke puts, 'Hello!'
       ret

   section '.idata' import data readable

   library msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll'

   import msvcrt,\
       puts,'puts'
   ```
4. Fasm, dos, через int 21h :)

   ```
   org 100h
       mov ah, 9
       mov dx, hello
       int 21h
       ret
       hello db 'Hello!$'
   ```

Answer (score -1):

MASM32+WinAPI

```
.686 
.model flat, stdcall

option casemap:none 
includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc 
includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib 
include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc

.data 
cWritten DWORD 0 
stdout DWORD 0 
_title db " " 
mess db "Hello, world!"

.code

_st:

invoke MessageBox, 0, ADDR mess, ADDR
_title, 0

invoke ExitProcess, 0

end _st
```

Comment:     cWritten DWORD 0
    stdout DWORD 0 

Это вообще из другой оперы.