# Почему нету вывода в консоль?

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

[image: е]

Почему нету вывода в консоль?!

Comment: В `dx` нужно загрузить _адрес_ строки.

Comment: ... вернее, в DS:DX.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, это fasm, там и так передается адрес строки (в fasm нет ключевого слова `offset`, `hello` - это адрес, а `[hello]` - это значение по адресу). Другое дело что исходник для досовского com-файла, а скомпилирован  в exe, и запускается под Windows (не в эмуляторе).

Answer (score 1):

Этот исходный код для досовского com файла. Нужно убрать `include 'win64ax.inc'`, тогда скомпилируется в файл `gnom.com`, который нужно запускать с помощью эмулятора DOS (например, DOSBox). Под современными версиями windows не запустится, т.к. из windows с некоторых пор выпилен эмулятор для запуска dos-овских исполняемых файлов.

Вывод в консоль под Windows - например варианты 2 и 3 из этого ответа: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/109848/1365