# Fasm x64 не выводит в консоль текст

Tags: windows, ассемблер, fasm, x86-64

```
    include 'win64ax.inc'

msg db "Hello",0
len=$-msg

_start:
            mov eax,4
            mov ebx,1
            mov ecx,msg
            mov edx,len
            int 0x80

            call exit
exit:
            mov eax, 1;
            mov ebx, 0;
            int 0x80
```

Когда я вызываю данную программу через cmd,то она ничего не выводит.

Answer (score 1):

Пример из вопроса - для Linux, под Windows он не заработает. Примеры из предыдущих ваших вопросов - для DOS, не заработают под Windows x64 без эмулятора DOS.

Адаптировал примеры 2 и 3 из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/109848/1365) для Win64. Изменения минимальные, хотя использование макроса `invoke` - это чит своего рода, это не одна машинная команда, а макрос, который при компиляции превращается в несколько машинных команд. В более сложных случая для адаптации для Win64 придется приложить больше усилий.

Примеры из ответа по ссылке (кроме последнего, он для DOS) создают 32-битные исполняемые файлы, которые вполне успешно запускаются под 64-битной Windows.

1. Голый [WinAPI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API)

   ```
   format pe64 console
   include 'win64ax.inc'

   .data
       hOut dq ?

   .code
       sHello db 'Hello!'
       .length = $ - sHello
       ; из текущего адреса вычитаем адрес метки sHello - получаем длину строки

   start:
       invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
       mov [hOut], rax
       invoke WriteConsole, [hOut], sHello, sHello.length, 0, 0
       invoke ExitProcess, 0

   .end start
   ```
2. С помощью [msvcrt.dll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_library_files#MSVCRT.DLL,_MSVCP*.DLL_and_CRTDLL.DLL) (*Microsoft Visual C Runtime*, библиотека с реализацией функций [стандартной библиотеки языка Си](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D0%B8))

   ```
   format pe64 console
   include 'win64ax.inc'

   section '.code' code readable executable
   start:
       cinvoke puts, 'Hello!'
       ret

   section '.idata' import data readable

   library msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll'

   import msvcrt,\
       puts, 'puts'
   ```

Что можно отметить: при программировании под Windows не используются прерывания (например, `int 21h` под DOS) или системные вызовы (`int 80h` или `syscall` под Linux), а используются функции из библиотек с читаемыми именами (в большинстве случаев). Если вы в интернете ищите примеры для Windows, а находите код с прерываниями или `syscall` - можно сразу листать дальше (исключение разве что команда `int3`, которую можно вставлять в код, чтобы при запуске программы под отладчиком происходила остановка на этом месте).

Бонус - первый вариант с выводом русского текста в юникоде. Так же, изменения минимальны
*(вспоминаются те костыли, которые приходится городить новичкам, чтобы заставить программу на С/C++ писать в консоль на русском)*:

```
format pe64 console
include 'win64wx.inc'
; w в win64wx.inc означает что будут использоваться юникодные версии функций WinAPI
; (например, WriteConsoleW вместо WriteConsoleA)

; Подключаем файл с макросом, переопределяющим инструкцию du,
; чтобы она понимала текст в соответствующей кодировке:
include 'encoding/utf8.inc'
; Или include 'encoding/win1251.inc' если код сохранен в кодировке win1251

.data
    hOut dq ?

.code
    sHello du 'Привет!' ; здесь du вместо db, каждый символ занимает 2 байта
    .length = ($ - sHello)/2
    ; Делим на 2, т.к. для WriteConsole нужна именно длина, а не количество байт.
    ; Вычисление происходит на этапе компиляции, не во время работы программы

start:
    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov [hOut], rax
    invoke WriteConsole, [hOut], sHello, sHello.length, 0, 0
    invoke ExitProcess, 0

.end start
```

[image: Скриншот]